# Reading a specific yaml value using Groovy

Tags: groovy, yaml

I have this yaml config file :

```
environmentMapping:
 ci-develop:
   inner: ABCD-npr-XA
   outer: ABCD-npr-XB
   outer-public: ABCD-npr-XC
   frontend: ABCD-npr-XD
 dev-develop:
   inner: BCDE-npr-ZA
   outer: BCDE-npr-ZB
   outer-public: BCDE-npr-ZC
   frontend: BCDE-npr-ZD
```

And would like to know how I can access a specific value.

here's my code :

```
  configs = readYaml file: 'configs.yaml'
  def env = 'ci-develop'
  def zone = 'inner'
  echo configs.environmentMapping.${env}.${zone}
```

This does not work.

How can I get the value for ci-develop -> inner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configs = readYaml file: 'configs.yaml'
def env = 'ci-develop'
def zone = 'inner'

echo configs.environmentMapping[env][zone]
```